# DataFrame to Teradata Database : [No more room in database] error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, teradata

**I have a :**

- connexion to the server of Teradata, called `connector`
- dataframe `df`,

**I want to : Save the dataframe in Teradata**

I did :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connector = create_engine(f'teradata://{username}:{password}@tdprod:22/')
df.to_sql('dataframe', connector)
```

But I have the following error :

```
[Teradata Database] [Error 2644] No more room in database {username}.
```

Can someone help me on this issue ?

Comment: You really should use `teradatasql` dialect / `teradatasqlalchemy` package. But the problem is your username likely has no PermSpace quota. You need a "Teradata database" where you have space and permission to create objects. Then either specify as the default `DATABASE=theName` in the URL or use `schema=theName` in to_sql

Comment: You are right: the problem was due to a user connexion. I used my username connection, whereas it was required my organization connexion. So in the variables of the teradatasqlalchemy connection, I indeed precised the `schema` of my global organization. Moreover, I added `index=False`. In the end I only changed 
 `df.to_sql('dataframe', scheme=my_schema, index=False, con=connector)`, and set the environment variables to the username of my organization.